# turn trailrenderer emitting off

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have code for timer of my trail

```
     private TrailRenderer tr;
     bool isEmit;
     float emitTimer;
     public float timeEmit = 2;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        tr = GetComponent<TrailRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (tr.emitting)
        {
            isEmit = true;
            emitTimer = timeEmit;
        }
        
        if (isEmit)
        {
            emitTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (emitTimer < 0)
            {
                isEmit = false;
                tr.emitting = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I go to my trigger and the trail is emitting, it won't stop emitting even though I set the timer to 2. Can someone see my error ?

Comment: This question is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (tr.emitting)
{
    isEmit = true;
    emitTimer = timeEmit;
}
```

Here is your problem.
You set `emitTimer = timeEmit` every frame, so `emitTimer` will always be 2.

Remove that line and do this:

Set `emitTimer = timeEmit` only once in the Start() Method and change your Update() method to this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (tr.emitting)
    {
        isEmit = true;
    }
    
    if (isEmit)
    {
        emitTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (emitTimer < 0)
        {
            isEmit = false;
            tr.emitting = false;
            emitTimer = timeEmit;
        }
    }
}
```